# Why does Java WebStart (JNLP) do multiple request to codebase/href?

Tags: java, httprequest, java-web-start, wireshark, jnlp

Steps to reproduce:

1. Start Whireshark, watching on local and sever IP address
2. Starting JNLP (with JAVA 8U60)

==> The codebase+href is called 3-times. Why?

Here is my jnlp:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp
  spec="1.0+"
  codebase="http://myserver/test"
  href="servlet/abc.jnlp?id=12345">
  <information>
    <title>tst jnlp</title>
    <vendor></vendor>
    <offline-allowed/>
    <shortcut online="true">
       <desktop/>
       <menu submenu="test"/>
    </shortcut>
  </information>
  <security>
      <all-permissions/>
  </security>
  <resources>
    <j2se version="1.6+" initial-heap-size="64m" max-heap-size="192m"/>
    <jar href="test.jar" main="true"/>
  </resources>
  <application-desc main-class="stack.overflow.Testclass"/>
</jnlp>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you define `href` atribute in `jnlp` tag, and run this jnlp file from your OS, Web Start will download jnlp file once again and will use a version form server. Remove `href` in `jnlp` tag.

Comment: That is OK so far but why does WebStart do it multiple times and not only once?

Comment: I have no idea :-( Look in to source code of web start ;-)